# How to reset the Maven repository profile to default for a particular project?

Tags: maven

I have created a new Maven project with IntelliJ and installing the dependencies, the `.m2` folder's `settings.xml` in my `${user.home}` folder has an active profile that contains the remote repository details for an internal repository, but for the current project I need to reset all those repository details without modifying the `.m2` folder's `settings.xml`, is there a way I can do it?

Comment: Can you explain that in more detail: `my system's root folder has an active profile that contains the remote repository details`?

Comment: @khmarbaise I guess with "_the .m2 folder ... has an active profile that contains the remote repository details_" he's most probably referring to [`${user.home}/.m2/settings.xml`](https://maven.apache.org/settings.html).

Comment: @khmarbaise BTW, There's something wrong with the code markup in https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html#deactivating-a-profile.

Comment: @khmarbaise thanks, added more details to the questions

Comment: thanks @GeroldBroser for pitching in I was precisely referring to the ${user.home}/.m2/settings.xml file, it has an internal repo link in the active profile that was preventing some dependencies to install therefore I wanted to disable it for a particulat project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Maven / Introduction to build profiles – Deactivating a profile](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html#deactivating-a-profile):

> Starting with Maven 2.0.10, one or more profiles can be deactivated using the command line by prefixing their identifier with either the character '!' or '-' as shown below:
>
> ```
> mvn groupId:artifactId:goal -P !profile-1,!profile-2,!?profile-3
> ```
>
> or
>
> ```
> mvn groupId:artifactId:goal -P -profile-1,-profile-2,-?profile-3
> ```
>
> This can be used to deactivate profiles marked as activeByDefault or profiles that would otherwise be activated through their activation config.

Answer (score 1):

I would just create an additional `settings-other.xml` and use it for Maven on the command line (with `-s settings-other.xml`).